# Custom NSTableHeaderCell for clear background of NSTableView

Tags: cocoa

I encountered a problem about clear background of NSTableView with custom NSTableHeaderCell. When I resizing the the table column.

[image]

```
// The method for setting NSTableView in some place
// NSScrollView disabled Draw Background
- (void)setMainTableView:(NSTableView *)mainTableView {

     _mainTableView = mainTableView;
     [_mainTableView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

     [[_mainTableView tableColumns] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        NSString *columnTitle = [[obj headerCell] stringValue];
        MyTableHeaderCell *myCell = [[MyTableHeaderCell alloc] initTextCell:columnTitle];
        [obj setHeaderCell:myCell];
    }];
 }

//  Overriding NSTableHeaderCell Method
- (void)drawWithFrame:(CGRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)view {

    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSFrameRect(cellFrame);

    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:view];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Radu

To be specific, for anyone who cares.. to do something like this in Swift you can do something like:

```
final class MyTableHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell
{
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(textCell: String)
    {
        super.init(textCell: textCell)
        // you can also set self.font = NSFont(...) here, too!        
    }

    override func drawWithFrame(cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView)
    {
        super.drawWithFrame(cellFrame, inView: controlView) // since that is what draws borders
        NSColor().symplyBackgroundGrayColor().setFill()
        NSRectFill(cellFrame)
        self.drawInteriorWithFrame(cellFrame, inView: controlView)
    }

    override func drawInteriorWithFrame(cellFrame: NSRect, inView controlView: NSView)
    {
        let titleRect = self.titleRectForBounds(cellFrame)
        self.attributedStringValue.drawInRect(titleRect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any previous pixels should be cleared automatically by the api before any drawing. It seems you found a glitch which happens only on resizing. A workaround is to clear the pixels yourself. Simply fill the cellFrame rect with white (or your background color) before drawing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 solution of Michaels solution:

```
final class MyTableHeaderCell : NSTableHeaderCell
{
    override init(textCell: String)
    {
        super.init(textCell: textCell)
        // you can also set self.font = NSFont(...) here, too!
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)
    {
        super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView) // since that is what draws borders
        NSColor.gray.setFill()
        cellFrame.fill()
        self.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }

    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)
    {
        let titleRect = self.titleRect(forBounds: cellFrame)
        self.attributedStringValue.draw(in: titleRect)
    }
}
```